# Java Unisex Bathroom Program using semaphores- Logic Issue

Tags: java, logic, semaphore

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
public class UnisexBathroom{
   static Semaphore bathroom;
   static Semaphore men_only;
   static Semaphore women_only;
public static void main(String[] args){
    if (args.length != 2) {
        printUsage();
    }

    int totMen = 0;
    int totWomen = 0;

    try {
        totMen = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        totWomen = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        printUsage();
    }

    bathroom= new Semaphore(1);
    men_only= new Semaphore(1);
    women_only= new Semaphore(1);

    System.out.println("Working\t\tEntering\tIn Bathroom\tLeaving");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");

    Thread[] men = new Thread[totMen];
    for (int i = 0; i < totMen; i++) {
        men[i] = new ManThread(i);
        men[i].start();
    }

    Thread[] women = new Thread[totWomen];
    for (int i = 0; i < totWomen; i++) {
        women[i] = new WomanThread(i);
        women[i].start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < totMen; i++) {
        try {
            men[i].join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < totWomen; i++) {
        try {
            women[i].join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    System.exit(0);
}

private static void printUsage() {
    System.out.println("Usage: java UnisexBathroom <totMen> <totWomen>");
    System.out.println("  <totMen>: Total number of men.");
    System.out.println("  <totWomen>: Total number of women.");
    System.exit(-1);
}

public static void randomSleep(int max) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * max));
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

private static class ManThread extends Thread {

    private int id;

    public ManThread(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void run() {
        doWork();
        if(UnisexBathroom.men_only.availablePermits()==0){
           useBathroom();
        }//if
        else{   
        try{
        UnisexBathroom.bathroom.acquire();
        UnisexBathroom.men_only.acquire();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
           System.out.println(e);
           System.exit(-1);
        }
        useBathroom();
        UnisexBathroom.men_only.release();
        UnisexBathroom.bathroom.release();
        }//else   
        doWork();           
    }//run

    private void doWork() {
        System.out.println("Man " + id);
        UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(10000);
    }

    private void useBathroom() {
        System.out.println("\t\tMan " + id);
        UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(100);
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tMan " + id);
        UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(500);
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tMan " + id);
        UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(100);
    }
}

private static class WomanThread extends Thread {

    private int id;

    public WomanThread(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void run() {
        doWork();
        if(UnisexBathroom.women_only.availablePermits()==0){
           useBathroom();
        }//if
        else{   
        try{
        UnisexBathroom.bathroom.acquire();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
           System.out.println(e);
           System.exit(-1);
        }  
        useBathroom();
        UnisexBathroom.women_only.release();
        UnisexBathroom.bathroom.release();
        }//else   
        doWork();
    }//run

    private void doWork() {
        System.out.println("Woman " + id);
        UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(10000);
    }

    private void useBathroom() {
        System.out.println("\t\tWoman " + id);
        UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(100);
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tWoman " + id);
        UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(500);
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tWoman " + id);
        UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(100);
    }
}
```

}

My program is suppose to only allow either a male or female into the bathroom and if a male is in then only another male can enter and vice versa for female. My question is of I am approaching this problem the correct way with the number of semaphores I am using and if I'm using them correctly. This is what happens when I run my code: [results](http://prntscr.com/aht8fp)[results](http://prntscr.com/aht7p2)

I'm sorry idk how to format my results properly so I included the hyperlink but basically when man 3, 1, and 2 enter Man 1 and 2 do not leave till after woman 1 enters which means two men and one women were in the bathroom which cannot happen. To reiterate, am I approaching this correctly with a logic error or approaching it incorrectly?

Comment: Okay, but then it's not really a unisex bathroom, is it?

Comment: i guess so but thats the way the requirements for the assignment were dictated. Direct quote "If a man is in bathroom, women must not enter till they leave(and vice versa)
If a man is in bathroom, another man does not have to wait ( and vice versa)"

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UnisexBathroom{
   static Semaphore bathroom;
   static Semaphore men_only;
   static Semaphore women_only;
public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner scIn = new Scanner(System.in);
int totMen = 0;
int totWomen = 0;
String Line;
    System.out.print("Total number of men:");
    totMen = scIn.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Total number of women:");
    totWomen = scIn.nextInt();
    Line = Rall(totMen,totWomen);
bathroom= new Semaphore(1);
men_only= new Semaphore(1);
women_only= new Semaphore(1);
System.out.println("m"+UnisexBathroom.men_only.availablePermits()+
                   "f"+UnisexBathroom.women_only.availablePermits()+
                   "b"+UnisexBathroom.bathroom.availablePermits());
System.out.println("Working\t\tEntering\tIn Bathroom\tLeaving");
System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");

Thread[] men = new Thread[Line.length()];
Thread[] women = new Thread[Line.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < Line.length(); i++) {
    if(Line.charAt(i)=='M'){
    men[i] = new ManThread(i);
    men[i].start();
    }
    if(Line.charAt(i)=='F'){
    women[i] = new WomanThread(i);
    women[i].start();
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i < Line.length(); i++) {
   if(Line.charAt(i)!=Line.charAt(i-1)){
        if(Line.charAt(i)=='M'){
            try {
                men[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UnisexBathroom.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }else{
            try {
                women[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UnisexBathroom.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
   }else{

   } 
}
System.exit(0);
}
private static String Rall(int x, int y){
String Output = "";  
Random rnd = new Random();
int male=0;
int female=0;
while(male!=x||female!=y){
    int R=rnd.nextInt(2);
    switch(R){
        case 0:
            if(male<x){
            Output=Output.concat("M");
            male++;}
            break;
        case 1:
            if(female<y){
            Output=Output.concat("F");
            female++;}
            break;
    }
} 
return Output;     
}

public static void randomSleep(int max) {
Random rnd = new Random();
int x = 1+rnd.nextInt(2);
try {
    Thread.sleep((int) (x* max));
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
}

private static class ManThread extends Thread {
private int id;

public ManThread(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void run() {
    doWork();
    if(UnisexBathroom.men_only.availablePermits()==0){
       useBathroom();
    }//if
    else{   
    try{
    UnisexBathroom.bathroom.acquire();
    UnisexBathroom.men_only.acquire();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
       System.out.println(e);
       System.exit(-1);
    }
    try{
    useBathroom();
    }finally{
    UnisexBathroom.men_only.release();
    UnisexBathroom.bathroom.release();
    }//else   
    System.out.print("E");doWork();    
    }
}//run

private void doWork() {
    System.out.println("Man " + id);
    UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(10000);
}

private void useBathroom() {
    System.out.println("\t\tMan " + id );
    UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(1000);
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tMan " + id );
    UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(3000);
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tMan " + id );
    UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(1000);
}
}

private static class WomanThread extends Thread {
private int id;

public WomanThread(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void run() {
    doWork(); 
    if(UnisexBathroom.women_only.availablePermits()==0){
       useBathroom();
    }//if
    else{   
    try{
    UnisexBathroom.bathroom.acquire();
    UnisexBathroom.women_only.acquire();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
       System.out.println(e);
       System.exit(-1);
    }
    try{
    useBathroom();
    }finally{
    UnisexBathroom.women_only.release();
    UnisexBathroom.bathroom.release();
    }//else   
    System.out.print("E");doWork();    
    }
}//run

private void doWork() {
    System.out.println("Woman " + id);
    UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(10000);
}

private void useBathroom() {
    System.out.println("\t\tWoman " + id );
    UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(2000);
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tWoman " + id );
    UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(5000);
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tWoman " + id );
    UnisexBathroom.randomSleep(2000);
}
}
}
```

You missed the aquire in Woman, Also i changed it a little bit but it still has the tendency to show that Woman is entering while Man is in the bathroom before it exits. (and vice versa).